# Create a lock slider clone in an iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, locking, slider

Short question! I want to make a slider (for a certain action), similar to the lock slider on the iPhone. How do I do this? Is it allowed? Are there any API's for this? Any help is greatly appreciated :-).

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 3):

Here is an opensource implementation hosted on Github
[Slide to Cancel](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/SlideToCancel)

However, I'd be very apprehensive using this in an app you wish to submit to the app store. Apple were granted a patent for the '*Slide to Unlock*' feature in 2010 and violating one of Apple's patents is a sure fire way to get your app rejected.